# Regex - Match each item between multiple occurrences of delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match the values between a given delimiter using a Regex expression in Python. I would like this to ignore surrounding white space. For example:

- The string `1, b cc, "a"`and delimiter `,` will return three matches of `1`,`b cc`,`"a"`
- The string `4 +   5 +   2  +1` and delimiter `+` will return four matches of `4`,`5`,`2`,`1`

Comment: [https://regex101.com/#python](https://regex101.com/#python) is an excellent website to build and test regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
line = '1, b cc, "a"'
re.split(r'[;,]\s*', line)
Out[7]: ['1', 'b cc', '"a"']

line = '4 +   5 +   2  +1'
re.split(r'\s*[+]\s*', line)
Out[10]: ['4', '5', '2', '1']
```

The `re.split()` function is useful because you can specify multiple patterns for the separator.

In this case, for your first request, the separator is either a `comma (,)`, `semicolon (;)`, followed by any amount of extra `whitespace`. For your second request, the separator is `plus (+)`, surrounded by any amount of extra `whitespaces`.

Whenever that pattern is found, the entire match becomes the delimiter between whatever fields lie on either side of the match. The result is a list of fields, just as with `str.split()`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) method.

```
import re

re.split('\s*,\s*', '1, b cc, "a"')

re.split('\s*\+\s*', '4 +   5 +   2  +1')
```